# Seaborn Jointplot Change Figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using Jupyter Notebook and want a full width jointplot figure.

I cant seem to get it working though.

```
g = sns.jointplot(x="pos", y="diff", data=plot_data)
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
```

doesn't change the size at all.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 6))
g = sns.jointplot(ax=ax, x="pos", y="diff", data=plot_data)
```

Throws an error.

Comment: You should make that your answer, as it does work.

Comment: okay, added as answer for others who might face a similar problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `height` parameter in the `jointplot` function to set the size of the figure(it will be square). Refer to official docs: [seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)

Comment: ```
g = sns.jointplot(ax=ax, x="pos", y="diff", data=plot_data);

g.fig.set_size_inches((5.5, 5))
```